# how to catch a non-fatal error in python

Tags: python, error-handling, tinycss

I'm using the parse_declaration_list function from [tinycss2](http://tinycss2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#tinycss2.ast.ParseError) which parses css. When I give it invalid css it returns [< ParseError invalid>]. However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to actually catch this error.

I've tried:

```
try:
    parse_declaration_list(arg)
except:
    do_something()
```

no dice.

```
try:
    parse_declaration_list(arg)[0]
except:
    do_something()
```

nope.

```
try:
    parse_declaration_list(arg)
except ParseError:
    do_something()
```

still nothing

```
error = parse_declaration_list(arg)[0]
if isinstance(error, Exception):
    do_something()
```

Sorry, no can do. I'm completely stumped and everything I google comes up with stuff about normal, well behaved errors.

Comment: can you post the traceback? `try/except` should catch _everything_ already.

Comment: maybe it's catched internally, then printed, then returns to your call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://tinycss2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#tinycss2.parse_declaration_list) indicates that the error is not raised, but returned, i.e. `try/except` won't work here. Instead, you have to check the result, as you do in your last approach. However, [`ParseError`](http://tinycss2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#tinycss2.ast.ParseError) seems not to be a subclass of `Exception`. Also, you probably can't just check the first element of the list. You can try something like this (not tested):

```
result = parse_declaration_list(arg)
if any(isinstance(r, tinycss2.ast.ParseError) for r in result):
    do_something()
```

Comment: Thank you! I almost go there. I'd tried "isinstance(result, tinycss2.ast.ParseError)", but it didn't work so I gave up on that tack.